# Are there standard rules and practices for Date serialization between two languages or frameworks?

Tags: python, objective-c, datetime, serialization, date

Seems simple but I just don't know.

I'm interested in serializing a date to a string or integer and sending it from Objective-C to Python, and I want to know if there's a way I *should* be doing it.

Sending the integer seconds since the Unix epoch seems pretty reasonable (and NSDate supplies that readily) but does Python datetime support that?

Is there an accepted string format for dates and serialization?

Comment: Are you looking for this? http://www.faqs.org/rfcs/rfc3339.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sure, Python can convert seconds from the Epoch to `datetime.datetime` objects:

```
In [23]: import datetime as dt
```

`fromtimestamp` returns the `datetime.datetime` in your machine's local timezone:

```
In [24]: dt.datetime.fromtimestamp(0)
Out[25]: datetime.datetime(1969, 12, 31, 19, 0)
```

`utcfromtimestamp` returns the UTC `datetime.datetime`:

```
In [26]: dt.datetime.utcfromtimestamp(0)
Out[26]: datetime.datetime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0)
```

Comment: What's the significance of the utc version of the method?

Comment: @Jasconius: If you are communicating between machines in different timezones, its easier if all machines work with UTC timestamps.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Python supports creating Date objects from Unix epoch time (although I'm not 100% sure it's in seconds, may be in ms)

Most languages should have built-in support for Unix time, and if not it wouldn't be hard to create a function to do so.